# Should we consider recursive call stack as auxiliary space?

Tags: java, c++, c, recursion, space-complexity

Should we consider recursive call stack as auxiliary space used by the program? I think it should be considered only when calculating space complexity, but not in calculating the auxiliary space.

---

Auxiliary Space is the extra space or temporary space used by an algorithm. Space Complexity of an algorithm is total space taken by the algorithm with respect to the input size.

Comment: Define "auxilliary space", and why is it important.

Comment: Auxiliary Space is the extra space or temporary space used by an algorithm. Space Complexity of an algorithm is total space taken by the algorithm with respect to the input size.

Comment: In future, please update the question with the extra information, rather than adding a comment.  I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Yes, of course. Why not? As you said yourself, "total space taken". Not just the innermost call.

Comment: The stack space used appears to count as 'auxilliary' space within your definition of the term.  It also counts as part of the total space.

Comment: ok.. thanks for replying guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually relying on variables in outer calls — if you'll need them again after your innermost call returns — then yes, they should be included in the auxiliary space.

But if all you have are [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), and the only reason your stack is growing is that your compiler doesn't support tail call optimization, then I don't think I would consider that in the auxiliary space of the (abstract) *algorithm*, even though your actual *implementation* will end up taking up that space.